# Is there way to parse leveldb to get transction trie of a given block?

Tags: go-ethereum

I see a couple of example on Internet about how to parse state trie from leveldb , is it possible to parse transaction trie and transaction receipt trie.

Comment: I am also looking for the same

Comment: @JitendraKumar.Balla well, there you go, check the answer

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. This is how `geth` does it:

```
func (p *StateProcessor) Process(block *types.Block, statedb *state.StateDB, cfg vm.Config) (types.Receipts, []*types.Log, uint64, error) {
    var (
        receipts types.Receipts
        usedGas  = new(uint64)
        header   = block.Header()
        allLogs  []*types.Log
        gp       = new(GasPool).AddGas(block.GasLimit())
    )
    // Mutate the the block and state according to any hard-fork specs
    if p.config.DAOForkSupport && p.config.DAOForkBlock != nil && p.config.DAOForkBlock.Cmp(block.Number()) == 0 {
        misc.ApplyDAOHardFork(statedb)
    }
    // Iterate over and process the individual transactions
    for i, tx := range block.Transactions() {
        statedb.Prepare(tx.Hash(), block.Hash(), i)
        receipt, _, err := ApplyTransaction(p.config, p.bc, nil, gp, statedb, header, tx, usedGas, cfg)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, nil, 0, err
        }
        receipts = append(receipts, receipt)
        allLogs = append(allLogs, receipt.Logs...)
    }
    // Finalize the block, applying any consensus engine specific extras (e.g. block rewards)
    p.engine.Finalize(p.bc, header, statedb, block.Transactions(), block.Uncles(), receipts)

    return receipts, allLogs, *usedGas, nil
}

// ApplyTransaction attempts to apply a transaction to the given state database
// and uses the input parameters for its environment. It returns the receipt
// for the transaction, gas used and an error if the transaction failed,
// indicating the block was invalid.
func ApplyTransaction(config *params.ChainConfig, bc *BlockChain, author *common.Address, gp *GasPool, statedb *state.StateDB, header *types.Header, tx *types.Transaction, usedGas *uint64, cfg vm.Config) (*types.Receipt, uint64, error) {
    msg, err := tx.AsMessage(types.MakeSigner(config, header.Number))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, 0, err
    }
    // Create a new context to be used in the EVM environment
    context := NewEVMContext(msg, header, bc, author)
    // Create a new environment which holds all relevant information
    // about the transaction and calling mechanisms.
    vmenv := vm.NewEVM(context, statedb, config, cfg)
    // Apply the transaction to the current state (included in the env)
    _, gas, failed, err := ApplyMessage(vmenv, msg, gp)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, 0, err
    }
    // Update the state with pending changes
    var root []byte
    if config.IsByzantium(header.Number) {
        statedb.Finalise(true)
    } else {
        root = statedb.IntermediateRoot(config.IsEIP158(header.Number)).Bytes()
    }
    *usedGas += gas

    // Create a new receipt for the transaction, storing the intermediate root and gas used by the tx
    // based on the eip phase, we're passing wether the root touch-delete accounts.
    receipt := types.NewReceipt(root, failed, *usedGas)
    receipt.TxHash = tx.Hash()
    receipt.GasUsed = gas
    // if the transaction created a contract, store the creation address in the receipt.
    if msg.To() == nil {
        receipt.ContractAddress = crypto.CreateAddress(vmenv.Context.Origin, tx.Nonce())
    }
    // Set the receipt logs and create a bloom for filtering
    receipt.Logs = statedb.GetLogs(tx.Hash())
    receipt.Bloom = types.CreateBloom(types.Receipts{receipt})

    return receipt, gas, err
}
```

Just modify these lines and add the code you want to add. Compile and run, you're done!

More info can be found in the sources:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/state_processor.go